# DICOM Image Viewer in Web using ClearCanvas SDK

Tags: asp.net, image, dicom

How can I configure ClearCanvas SDK to use with my Web application? I want to use the image viewer with one of my web page (say, ImageViewer.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a discussion about doing this on the official ClearCanvas site, actually started by one of the authors. (CC now has a web viewer available). Please see:

http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/Community/Forums/tabid/69/aff/8/aft/14658/afv/topic/afpg/1/Default.aspx